# I wrote go code on macos(m2) using aws-sdk-cpp and libtorch(cpp) through cgo but got an errormessage: [ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64]

Tags: go, cgo, libtorch, aws-sdk-cpp

#### my cgo args:

```
/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/libtorch/lib -ltorch -lc10 -lkineto -ltorch_cpu -laws-cpp-sdk-s3 -laws-cpp-sdk-sts -laws-cpp-sdk-iam -laws-cpp-sdk-core
#cgo CXXFLAGS: -std=c++14 -I/usr/local/libtorch/include -v // I added -arch arm64 but not working
#include "NDInferenceModel_capi.h"
*/
import "C"
```

#### This is my zsh output.

[The full output is here.](http://paste.org.cn/x8NQaVH2SJ)

zsh and output:

```
$go run main.go
# go_dsp/pkg/mlmodel_nd
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple arm64-apple-macosx13.0.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name NDInferenceModel.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=non-leaf -fno-strict-return -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -funwind-tables=1 -fobjc-msgsend-selector-stubs -target-sdk-version=13.3 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden-static-local-var -target-cpu apple-m1 -target-feature +v8.5a -target-feature +crc -target-feature +lse -target-feature +rdm -target-feature +crypto -target-feature +dotprod -target-feature +fp-armv8 -target-feature +neon -target-feature +fp16fml -target-feature +ras -target-feature +rcpc -target-feature +zcm -target-feature +zcz -target-feature +fullfp16 -target-feature +sm4 -target-feature +sha3 -target-feature +sha2 -target-feature +aes -target-abi darwinpcs -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debug-info-kind=standalone -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 857.1 -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/Users/shaochong/iplayable/branch/20230630/go_dsp/pkg/mlmodel_nd -resource-dir /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.3 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I pkg/mlmodel_nd -I $WORK/b583/ -I /usr/local/libtorch/include -I/usr/local/include -stdlib=libc++ -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.3/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include -O2 -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -Wno-elaborated-enum-base -Wno-reserved-identifier -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -std=c++14 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/Users/shaochong/iplayable/branch/20230630/go_dsp/pkg/mlmodel_nd -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/1t/j0gmyq2178n6jjv13k8xwmbm0000gn/T/go-build455358925/b583=/tmp/go-build -ferror-limit 19 -pthread -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fno-cxx-modules -no-opaque-pointers -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fno-caret-diagnostics -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -clang-vendor-feature=+disableNonDependentMemberExprInCurrentInstantiation -fno-odr-hash-protocols -clang-vendor-feature=+enableAggressiveVLAFolding -clang-vendor-feature=+revert09abecef7bbf -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoAlignAttr -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoNullAttr -mllvm -disable-aligned-alloc-awareness=1 -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o $WORK/b583/_x003.o -x c++ NDInferenceModel.cpp
clang -cc1 version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1) default target arm64-apple-darwin22.5.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 pkg/mlmodel
 $WORK/b581
 /usr/local/libtorch/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.3/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
# command-line-arguments
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: running clang++ failed: exit status 1
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "Aws::Crt::ApiAllocator()", referenced from:
      Aws::InitAPI(Aws::SDKOptions const&) in libaws-cpp-sdk-core.a(Aws.cpp.o)
      Aws::Endpoint::DefaultEndpointProvider<Aws::S3::S3ClientConfiguration, Aws::S3::Endpoint::S3BuiltInParameters, Aws::S3::Endpoint::S3ClientContextParameters>::DefaultEndpointProvider(char const*, unsigned long) in libaws-cpp-sdk-s3.a(ub_S3.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I added `-arch arm64` to `#cgo CXXFLAGS` but not working.

I added `-arch arm64` to `#cgo CXXFLAGS` but not working.
I hope I can use go run main.go to compile code normally.